# Grouping and querying content in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am attempting to set up a shared content repository in Umbraco 7. Ideally I would like something like:

```
ParentGroup
--SubGroup
----contentItem
```

I would like this structure and then I would like sub sites to be able to pick and choose which content they use, whilst keeping the grouping. I've looked at the [multi node tree picker](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/multinode-treepicker) and this looks promising.

I am struggling however with how to organise the content into groups, a group would really be a text label, do I just create a content type without a template for this or is there a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating a document type without a template is the way to go. Every content item in the content tree is defined by it's documenttype and it's perfectly reasonable that not every content item translates directly to a page, thus not having a template.